# Writing Dictionaries into a CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraping project, I am trying to save the results into a CSV file,

```
  data = { 
       'address_area': area,
       'address_district': district,
       'website': website,
       'branch_rating': rating,
       'facilities_delivery': delivery,
       'facilities_banquet': banquet,
        'facilites_shisha': shisha,
        'faciliteis_minumum': minumium,
        'facilites_reservation': reservation,
        'facilities_free_wifi': wifi,
        'facilities_smoking_permited': smoking,
        'facilities_eat_out': eat_out,
        'facilities_private_parking': parking,
        'facilities_price_range': price_range,
        'facilities_kids_ares': kids_ares,
        'branch_no': branch_no}
mainlist.append(data)
with open('filetest.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for value in mainlist:
        writer.writerow([value])
```

I want to save the key in the dictionary as columns and the values as a row,
(keep in mind that the value pair in the dictionary refers to a variable that extracts data from a web site)

Comment: The column headers only need to be written once, so in the solution I created below I added this line "headers = ",".join(data1.keys())" to make a comma delimited list of header columns for the top of the CSV.  The rest of the code is just enumerating the dictionary values and making CSV outputs.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that can work for you.  I added a second data item to your code (data2) and renamed the initial data element to data1.

```
mainlist = []

#initial data item
data1 = { 
       'address_area': 'area1',
       'address_district': 'district1',
       'website': 'website1',
       'branch_rating': 'rating1',
       'facilities_delivery': 'delivery1',
       'facilities_banquet': 'banquet1',
        'facilites_shisha': 'shisha1',
        'faciliteis_minumum': 'minumium1',
        'facilites_reservation': 'reservation1',
        'facilities_free_wifi': 'wifi1',
        'facilities_smoking_permited': 'smoking1',
        'facilities_eat_out': 'eat_out1',
        'facilities_private_parking': 'parking1',
        'facilities_price_range': 'price_range1',
        'facilities_kids_ares': 'kids_aresa1',
        'branch_no': 'branch_no1'}
mainlist.append(data1)

#second data item
data2 = { 
       'address_area': 'area2',
       'address_district': 'district2',
       'website': 'website2',
       'branch_rating': 'rating2',
       'facilities_delivery': 'delivery2',
       'facilities_banquet': 'banquet2',
        'facilites_shisha': 'shisha2',
        'faciliteis_minumum': 'minumium2',
        'facilites_reservation': 'reservation2',
        'facilities_free_wifi': 'wifi2',
        'facilities_smoking_permited': 'smoking2',
        'facilities_eat_out': 'eat_out2',
        'facilities_private_parking': 'parking2',
        'facilities_price_range': 'price_range2',
        'facilities_kids_ares': 'kids_aresa2',
        'branch_no': 'branch_no2'}     
mainlist.append(data2)

filename = 'filetest.csv'
headers = ",".join(data1.keys())
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(headers + '\n')
    for item in mainlist:
        f.write(','.join(str(item[key]) for key in item) + '\n')
print("All done.  Check this file for results:",filename)
```

Comment: May I ask why did you create another item (data2) and how it works?

Comment: The second item (data2) was just to help demonstration what the CSV file might look like when you have multiple records.  It shows that each input item (data1, data2 or another item) gets its own row in the CSV.

Comment: You can leave out the line "mainlist.append(data2)" and the code will still work fine.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an upvote for helping solve your challenge?